# How do you pass an argument with xcrun swift in CLI?

Tags: swift, xcrun

With Xcode installed, I would like to compile and run a .swift file in the command line. Understood, this can be done:

```
xcrun swift sayHello.swift
```

However, I would like to pass an argument in the command line.

For example, with the following function in sayHello.swift:

```
func sayHello(personName: String) -> String {
    let greeting = "Hello, " + personName + "!"
    return greeting
}
```

How do you pass an argument, e.g. Bob? 
This looked promising:

> -D              Specifies one or more build configuration options

```
xcrun swift -D sayHello(Bob) sayHello.swift
```

But, it's not what I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass arbitrary *strings* as command-line arguments to the process, but you
cannot expect that they are executed as *code* (like `sayHello(Bob)`).

In Swift, `Process.arguments` is a string array with all command-line
arguments given to the process. The first element (at index 0) is
the path to the executable itself, and the additional command-line
arguments start at index 1:

```
// sayHello.swift

func sayHello(personName: String) -> String {
    let greeting = "Hello, " + personName + "!"
    return greeting
}

let args = Process.arguments
for i in 1 ..< args.count {
    let name = args[i]
    let greeting = sayHello(name)
    println(greeting)
}
```

Example:

```
$ xcrun swift sayHello.swift Peter Paul Mary
Hello, Peter!
Hello, Paul!
Hello, Mary!
```